# Where MouseEvent objects are created in Java

Tags: java, events, input, mouse

I am trying to track how Java processes the mouse input.

So far, I've learned that whenever mouse device is clicked/moved the actual data on it's state is stored in a file (ie. in Linux it's /dev/input/mouse0 or mice file), then Java reads file through java.io.ObjectInputStream  and creates java.awt.MouseEvent which is then passed by java.awt.Component (through java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster) to any of Component's mouse listeners where the MouseEvent object is handled.

My question is - where in Java are MouseEvent objects actually created?

I am not interested in Observer pattern and information how MouseEvents are handled but how particular java.awt.MouseEvent is created from mouse input.
I would expect that there is somewhere "new MouseEvent(...) " sentence, but I can't find it anywhere. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are handled inside of base objects represents components for example for AWT it is Component.java

as you can see here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Component.java

It is using AWTEventMulticaster:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster.html

Which is implementation of efficient and thread-safe multi-cast event dispatching for AWTEvents.

Hope i helped.

Comment: Yes, AWTEventMulticaster is dispatching events to Component's listeners but where these events (MouseEvent particularly) come from? There is no code in AWTEventMulticaster nor in Component class that actually creates MouseEvent object.

Comment: As Danny said. MouseEvent is Java type for events dispatched by mouse (hardware) on each platform (OSs, Win, Linux) Java Virtual Machine has different Responder instance. For example in OSs. It is CPlatformResponder which calls LWWindowPeer for dispatching java mouse event. Responder is interface between hardware and java virtual machine and CPlatformResponder change hardware calls to java types like MouseEvent or KeyEvent using LWWindowPeer where is called new MouseEvent https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17983141/#l-42

Answer (score 0):

I used the IntelliJ IDE to put a breakpoint on all the `MouseEvent` constructors and discovered that `MouseEvent` creation happens in the `sun.lwawt.*` package space, (specifically on a Mac, but I suspect something similar occurs for other OSs).  For my machine, the stacktrace contains:

```
    <init>(): 733, MouseEvent (java.awt.event)
    dispatchMouseEvent(): 775, LWWindowPeer (sun.lwawt)
    handleMouseEvent(): 80, CPlatformResponder (sun.lwawt.macosx)
    deliverMouseEvent(): 195, CPlatformView (sun.lwawt.macosx)
```